# How do I update one of model having relation each other?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I try to update 2 model with following steps.

1. Article

   - id
   - current_version
   - status
2. ArticleHistory

   - id
   - article_id
   - title
   - content
   - version

These models have relationship with article_id and current_version = version.

First, we made one record like this.

```
article.id:1
article.current_version:1
article.status:public
article_history.id:1
article_history.title:"test title"
article_history.content:"test content"
article_history.version:1
```

And I'm going to update like this. Before that, I'd like to copy existing ArticleHistory record with new id. I mean, it's like renewing ArticleHistory.

```
article.id:1
article.current_version:2
article.status:public
(copied)article_history.id:2
(copied)article_history.title:"updated test title"
(copied)article_history.content:"updated test content"
(copied)article_history.version:2
```

But now, I can't figure out how to express by RoR ActiveRecord.
After this modification, Article has got multiple record.

Give me advise, please.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Article
  has_many :article_histories
```

should do the trick. If you need more, the doco for has_many is here:

http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many

If this is not suitable - then please tell us why it doesn't work for you :)

To copy...

```
# first find the article_history with the highest version for this article
latest_history = article.article_histories.order(:version).last
# if there isn't one, create a new one
if latest_history.blank?
  new_history = article.article_histories.new(params[:article_history])
  new_history.version = 1
else
  # Otherwise... merge params and the old attributes
  combined_attributes = latest_history.attributes.merge(params[:article_history])
  # and use that to create the newer article_history version
  new_history = article.article_histories.build(combined_attributes)
  new_history.version = latest_history.version + 1
end
new_history.save!
```

Note: this code is just to give you an idea of how it could be done.
You will need to bugfix it and make it actually work yourself.

Comment: Great! Let me check this code later. I'll get back as soon as it turns out.